# Custom Wicket (Ajax) Control with complex data model

Tags: javascript, d3.js, components, wicket

We are giving Wicket (v8) a try for a project, and I am wondering about what's the best practice for the following scenario:

- We have a database library function which returns a `List<ComplexObject>`.
- The call is being handled within some `IModel`
- We want to render a d3 visualization backed by this model, let's call it `ComplexVisualization`.
- The model needs to be rendered to some JavaScript variable (as JSON), such that our d3 code can use that as input.
- The user can make some changes in other controls such that the database library call would generate a different `List<ComplexObject>`
- When the ComplexVisualization is added as Ajax Target the JavaScript variable need to update its value accordingly, and some custom JavaScript method needs to be triggered such that we can refresh the d3 visualization.

I am looking for some code example where someone could point out which Class `ComplexVisualization` should extend from, how we could render some HTML for this component (if necessary), and especially how to have one JavaScript variable in sync with the `IModel<List<ComplexObject>>`.

Thanks for help & suggestions,

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ComplexVisualization may have method `toJson()` that serializes it to JSON. In addition it may have method `update()` that returns String like: `"window.updateVisualization(" + toJson() +")"`. This way you should use `target.appendJavaScript(complexVisualization.update())`.

The JavaScript method `updateVisualization` should be defined by JavaScriptHeaderItem contribution, e.g. in my-lib.js.

Comment: `target.appendJavaScript` was the missing piece! Great, thank you for pointing this one out!